# Progress Bar Stairs

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

i'm just getting started with developing Android Apps. Therefore i have a question, for designing my GUI. Maybe there is a possible build-in widget, but i don't have the right wording to find it (English is not my native language).

I'm looking for something like the Rating Bar, where you can select a value between 1 and 5. Instead of the stars, i'd like to have some bars (the left one is the smallest, the right one the highest). Should look like the "Stairs" within a Signal strength notification. To make it a bit more challenging i'd like to have different colors for every bar (least value is green, highest value red). Therefore i don't think that the Rating Bar with different drawings will fit my needs, because afaik i could just change the star layout, not like the first star should become a 5dp bar, the second a 15dp and so on.

Is there any build in widget i could use?

I attached a picture to show my idea.

[image: image view]

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you want is easily achievable with a `level-list`. In your case you need five different drawables, on for each level and then combine them in a drawable xml file, like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/no_level"
    android:maxLevel="0" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/first_level"
    android:maxLevel="1" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/second_level"
    android:maxLevel="2" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/third_level"
    android:maxLevel="3" />

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/forth_level"
    android:maxLevel="4" />
</level-list>
```

and set this drawable as source for an `ImageView`, for instance. At runtime, retrieve the `ImageView` and call `setImageLevel`, with a value from 0 and 4, and the corresponding level will be displayed

Comment: Okay, nice, thank you :) Is it possible to detect on which Bar (or part of the drawable) the user clicks? Like for example, when i want the user to set the imagelevel directly to 3 when he touches the third bar?

Comment: not with the level-list solution. I probably misread your question. Why can't you use the RatingBar ?

Comment: I like the solution with the level-list - the display is exact the way i want it. but i'd like to have a clickable component to change the imagelevel (like the rating bar). I thought for customising the rating bar it might be difficult to have 5 different level bars instead of 5 same looking stars. or is it the same way you edit the appearance for the rating bar like the level-list solution?

Comment: it's slightly more complicated but you will get both. on the RatingBar you have to use a custom style, in order to customize the `progressDrawable`. You could try to combine both but I am not sure it is gonna work. For the sake of the simplicity I would suggest you to use the `level-list` approach

Comment: Okay, looks like it doesn't work. The RatingBar could be customized via progressdrawable but you could only change the appearence of one star (empty and full). so there is no way, to make different sized bars i think.